# How can i pull a string from a string of words?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string "Date between March 2018 and June 2018" or the string could be like
"Show me the date between March 2018 and June 2018".

so I want to store the first month year i.e., March 2018 in one variable and the next Month year i.e., June 2018 in another variable.

month can be December , October.. etc.

I want to write a code in **JavaScript** to store any 2 month year in 2 separate variables.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include the code you've written that you are having problems with.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract parts of the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "show me the date between March 2018 and June 2018";
    var date1 = str.substr(25, str.indexOf('and')-25);
    var date2 = str.substr(str.indexOf('and')+4,9);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date1 +' <br/> '+ date2;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Put your code in your question.

Comment: Doing such stuff in `JS` seems like an exploitation, why not consider doing it serverside? Is this your homework?

Comment: This code is not dynamic... if the month changes to December it will not give me the desired output

Comment: i just want to use it this functionality in another js

Comment: I would like to know only the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question wasn't really written appropriately, the following code will work:

```
const months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];

const reg = new RegExp(`(${months.join('|')})\\s[\\d]{4}`, 'gi');
const str = 'Date between March 2018 and June 2018';
const matches = str.match(reg).map((item) => item.split(' '));
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: You should get rid of that `+` in your RegExp, otherwise you'll match strings like `JanunaryJanunary 2018`.

Comment: Again if I have the same string.. "Date between March 2018 and June 2018" How will we put the Months between March 2018 & June 2018 into an array .. i.e., strings ... March 2018 , April 2018, May 2018 , June 2018 into an array

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following  `RegExp` for that:

```js
const str = "Show me the date between March 2018 and June 2018";

const [start, end] = str.match(/((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{4})/gi);

console.log(start, end);
```

Comment: Again if I have the same string.. "Date between March 2018 and June 2018" How will we put the Months between March 2018 & June 2018 into an array .. i.e., strings ... March 2018 , April 2018, May 2018 , June 2018 into an array ?

Comment: @Shrey you would just need to assign the the matched item array to a variable:

const str = "Show me the date between March 2018 and June 2018";

const arr = str.match(/((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{4})/gi);

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to get every *month-year* couple ot the string and store every match into an array

Here's the code:

```js
var str = "Show me the date between March 2018, June 2018 and December 2019"; 
var res = str.match(/(\w*\s\d{4})/g);

console.log(res);
```

Now you just have to iterate over the array and do whatever you want with each value.

Hope you find it helpfully.

Comment: Again if I have the same string.. "Date between March 2018 and June 2018" How will we put the Months between March 2018 & June 2018 into an array .. i.e., strings ... March 2018 , April 2018, May 2018 , June 2018 into an array

Answer (score -1):

You can use the split function to split the string and extract the useful information.

I've written a script for you on jsfiddler.

Please have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o5rhab7s/6/)

```
var temp="Date between March 2018 and June 2018";
var fields=temp.split(' ');
var date2=fields[fields.length-2] +" "+fields[fields.length-1];

var date1=fields[fields.length-5] +" "+fields[fields.length-4];
alert(date1);//March 2018
alert(date2);//June 2018
```

Comment: This should not be de acepted answer. The code is absolutely static, I mean that if the string is not exactly the one in the example, it does not work properly. You should be able to detect any month-year couple dynamically.

Comment: Again if I have the same string.. "Date between March 2018 and June 2018"

How will we put the Months between March 2018 & June 2018 into an array .. i.e., strings ... March 2018 , April 2018, May 2018 , June 2018 into an array